# MBProgressHUD resets positions of UIViews during Loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, mbprogresshud

I have a View Controller (iPad landscape) that has some `UIView` and a `UIScrollView`, and a `UIButton`.

The `UIScrollView` is showing at 1024 x 60 on screen, while its content has size 2048 x 60. That means, it can scroll horizontally. Its `contentOffset` is set to (1024, 0), while, its `contentSize` is set to 2048 x 60.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.scrollHeader setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2048, 60)];
    [self.scrollHeader setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1024, 0)];
    [self.scrollHeader setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

For few `UIView`, they are 50 x 50 in size. They are programmed to drag around (stop when touch ended) via `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. (since the drag codes are too long, won't post here)

Last, the `UIButton` is linked with a function via `IBAction`, called `clickNext`, which is basically adding `MBProgressHUD` on screen and execute `AFNetworking`.

```
- (IBAction)clickNext {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNetworkResponse:) name:@"NetworkNotification" object:nil];
    self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    self.hud.labelText = @"Loading";
    [self.hud show:YES];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // AFNetworking POST request omitted
}
```

After the `AFNetworking` work is done, `MBProgressHUD` is set to hidden.

The problem is, when I click the button, `MBProgressHUD` shows up, the `UIView` resets to original position, while the content offset of `UIScrollView` jumps to (0, 0). Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

I don't even know which line causes the issue, but I'm quite sure that there is no warning / error.

Comment: MBProgressHUD is open source, so you can investigate what happens when you show it. I use it in many projects and your problem never occurred to me.

Comment: I used it in many projects too; never happened so far. I used Cocoapods to install the latest version.